# Using memory while deleting extra spaces

Tags: python, algorithm, memory

I need to remove extra spaces in string. And I need to use O(1) memory. Is it possible to not use lists, because lists use more memory than strings (I've checked it with `sys.getsizeof()`) or when I use `split()` I'm still using O(1) memory?

There is code

```
s = input()
s = s.split('_')
s = list(filter(lambda a: a != '', s))
print('_'.join(s))
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You can edit the question and add the code :)

Comment: Actually I need to remove extra lowercases

Comment: Strings are immutable in python, so removing spaces will result in a new string of comparable length to the original. That makes it impossible to solve this problem in O(1) space.

Answer (score 1):

I would usually do this to remove extra spaces

```py
text = ' '.join(text.split()).strip()
```

Though if you don't want to use list you can use regex

```py
import re
text = re.sub(r' {2,}', ' ', text).strip()
```

Comment: Is there a way to check that this is `O(1)` ?

Comment: It seems the second method satisfies the condition and use O(1) memory

Comment: How do you know for sure?

Comment: It's not O(1) in time or space. It's O(n) time, O(n) space (and no solution can be better in terms of efficiency).